# Parsing XML responses

Tags: xml, parsing, elementtree

```
import requests
import httplib
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()

username = 'admin'
password = 'xxxxxxxxx'
url='https://xx.xx.xx.xx/nuova'

root = Element('aaaLogin')
tree = ElementTree(root)
root.set('inName', username)
root.set('inPassword', password)

payload = etree.tostring(root)

myheaders={'Content-Type':'application/xml'}

try:
    response = requests.post(url,verify=False,data=payload,headers=myheaders).text

except httplib.IncompleteRead as e:
    response = e.partial

tree = etree.fromstring(response.decode('utf-8'))
data = tree.attrib

cookie = data['outCookie']

root = Element('configResolveDn')
tree = ElementTree(root)
root.set('cookie', cookie)
root.set('dn', 'sys/chassis-1/blade-1')
root.set('inHierarchical', 'false')

payload = etree.tostring(root)

print(payload + "\n")

myheaders={'Content-Type':'application/xml'}

try:
    response = requests.post(url,verify=False,data=payload,headers=myheaders).text

    print(response + "\n")

except httplib.IncompleteRead as e:
    response = e.partial

tree = etree.fromstring(response.decode('utf-8'))
data = tree.attrib

print (data.keys())
```

---

Debug Output:

```
<configResolveDn cookie="1440623962/bdcb3317-2b8a-4488-a354-b73dcb03418e" dn="sys/chassis-1/blade-1" inHierarchical="false" />

 <configResolveDn dn="sys/chassis-1/blade-1" cookie="1440623962/bdcb3317-2b8a-4488-a354-b73dcb03418e" response="yes"> <outConfig> <computeBlade adminPower="policy" adminState="in-service" assignedToDn="org-root/org-AS-BXB/ls-N1Kv4.2.1-SV2-2.1-Lab-Server1" association="associated" availability="unavailable" availableMemory="49152" chassisId="1" checkPoint="discovered" connPath="A,B" connStatus="A,B" descr="" discovery="complete" dn="sys/chassis-1/blade-1" fltAggr="4294967296" fsmDescr="" fsmFlags="" fsmPrev="TurnupSuccess" fsmProgr="100" fsmRmtInvErrCode="none" fsmRmtInvErrDescr="" fsmRmtInvRslt="" fsmStageDescr="" fsmStamp="2015-05-09T20:53:44.371" fsmStatus="nop" fsmTry="0" intId="717104" lc="undiscovered" lcTs="1969-12-31T19:00:00.000" localId="" lowVoltageMemory="low-voltage" managingInst="B" memorySpeed="1067" mfgTime="2011-10-07T01:00:00.000" model="N20-B6625-1" name="" numOfAdaptors="1" numOfCores="12" numOfCoresEnabled="12" numOfCpus="2" numOfEthHostIfs="6" numOfFcHostIfs="2" numOfThreads="24" operPower="on" operQualifier="" operState="ok" operability="operable" originalUuid="02a1ff71-f03c-11e0-bd1d-00101859a783" partNumber="74-7334-02" policyLevel="0" policyOwner="local" presence="equipped" revision="0" serial="QCI1539ABCH" serverId="1/1" slotId="1" totalMemory="49152" usrLbl="" uuid="ba5eba11-9999-0002-0000-000000000002" vendor="Cisco Systems Inc" vid="V02"/> </outConfig> </configResolveDn>

['dn', 'cookie', 'response']
```

I am able to build and send valid XML to the network device, but I can't seem to correctly parse the responses. How can I get the 'data' dictionary to contain tag:attribute for outConfig as well as configResolveDn?

Comment: What does "can't seem to correctly parse" mean?  Are you getting an error, is it not parsing right? If so what output are you getting?

Comment: The 'data' dictionary only contains tag:attributes for configResolveDn and I would like it to contain outConfig as well.    print (data.keys()) give this output ['dn', 'cookie', 'response'], I was expecting [adminPower,adminState ...etc.

Comment: data = tree[0][0].attrib worked for me. Thanks Rick for taking the time.